# Mockito verify fails in second unit test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito together to JUnit to implement unit tests for a class in an Android project.The problem is that I call `Mockito.verify` in two consequent tests where the tests are exactly same (to make sure that I am using Mockito correctly) but the interesting thing is that verify in second test always fails.I suspect that some operations need to be done before each test using `@before` annotation or so, that I have missed.Here are some code snippet about what I am doing.

I use Android Studio 3.4.1, Mockito 2.7.22 and JUnit 4.12.

```
@Test
public void test_onStart_do_nothing() throws Exception {
    ZConnectionService zConnectionService = new ZConnectionService();
    ZConnection mockedZConnection = mock(ZConnection.class);

    doNothing().when(mockedZConnection).connect();
    zConnectionService.initConnection(mockedZConnection);

    verify(mockedZConnection, times(1)).connect();
}

@Test
public void test_onStart_throw_IO_exceptioon() throws Exception {
    ZConnectionService zConnectionService = new ZConnectionService();
    ZConnection mockedZConnection = mock(ZConnection.class);

    doNothing().when(mockedZConnection).connect();
    zConnectionService.initConnection(mockedZConnection);
    // Line above is the line that error message points to!

    verify(mockedZConnection, times(1)).connect();
}
```

Here comes the function under test

```
public void initConnection(ZConnection connection) {
    Log.d(TAG,"initConnection()");

    if (mConnection == null) {
        mConnection = connection;
    }

    if (!mActive) {
        mActive = true;

        if (mThread == null || !mThread.isAlive()) {
            mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // The code here runs in a background thread.
                    Looper.prepare();
                    mTHandler = new Handler();

                    try {
                        mConnection.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Intent i = null;
                        i = new Intent(ZConnectionService.UI_NOTCONNECTED);
                        i.setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(i);

                        e.printStackTrace();

                        // Stop the services all together.
                        stopSelf();
                    }

                    Looper.loop();
                }
            });

            mThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect that both tests should pass without any problem. In fact, both tests are passed when I ran them individually, but they fail when I run the whole suite and the error is:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
mockedZinkConnection.connect();
-> at com.app.z.ZConnectionServiceUnitTest.test_onStart_throw_IO_exceptioon(ZConnectionServiceUnitTest.java:207)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: Are these really your tests? Currently they are exactly the same and should run perfectly fine.

Comment: Side note `verify(mockedZConnection, times(1))` can be shortened to `verify(mockedZConnection)`, which does exactly the same

Comment: @Dan can you post the code of the ZConnectionService.initConnection method?

Comment: No they are not real tests of course! They are exactly same! I altered second test after it was failed and now I see that when two consequent tests are exactly same they fail too! I am wondering why?

Comment: Sure I will edit the question and post the function under test.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your test configuration, and it isn't getting updated. You can try running `./gradlew test` from the command line (assuming you're on linux), or click the "edit configurations" tab near the top of your IDE and delete all previous configs. It may be running an old one. Both these tests should give exactly the same output.

Comment: I have 2 ideas: 1) (unlikely) static fields in `ZConnectionService` 2) (very likely) Simply a timing issue. You connect in a separate thread, but you don't wait for the thread to do it's job.

Comment: Good point! How can I make the tests synched? I mean in the first test, I guess I should wait until the thread is joined and then start new test. How can I wait for the thread in each test? Is there any straightforward way to do so? Thanks!

Comment: @Dan I think you have issues with the Thread. You might not have called connect() yet when you call the verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is a multithreading one. 
When you call `initConnection`, it calls `mConnection.connect()` in a `Thread`
The problem you are having is that this `Thread` takes some time to complete and you end up calling `verify(mockedZConnection, times(1)).connect();` before the Thread actually reached the `connect()` call.
A way to make sure about it is to join the `Thread` after you start it, it will wait until the `Thread` has finished before continuing:

```
mThread.start();
try {
    mThread.join();
} catch (InterruptedException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();

}
```

Now both tests should work.

This of course is not acceptable in the code, because it negated the use of a `Thread`. You will need an other way to test it.

A way I can think of would be to wait for the Thread to complete in your test before checking the mock:

```
@Test
public void test_onStart_throw_IO_exceptioon() throws Exception {
    ZConnectionService zConnectionService = new ZConnectionService();
    ZConnection mockedZConnection = mock(ZConnection.class);
    doNothing().when(mockedZConnection).connect();

    zConnectionService.initConnection(mockedZConnection);

    // Wait for the Thread to complete
    while(zConnectionService.mThread.isAlive()) {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    verify(mockedZConnection, times(1)).connect();
}
```

Tried and it works fine for me. Not sure it is a best practice though as you need to make public some internals of your class, which violates encapsulation

maybe having a package protected `isThreadAlive()` method on your `ZConnectionService` class could be acceptable

```
boolean isThreadAlive() {
    return mThread.isAlive();
}
```

and the loop in the test

```
while(zConnectionService.isThreadAlive()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Comment: Yes this was the correct solution! I had to wait inside each test to make sure that the thread is done before starting a new test. Thanks for the help!